# vue without App.vue and "render: h => h(App)"?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, font-awesome

i have inherited a vue app which does not contain a App.vue file and no "render: h => h(App)" when calling new Vue :-|.

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

it is working, but i don't know if this is good or not :-D. when i try to add font-awesome like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');
    
window.Vue = require('vue');

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faHatWizard } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';

library.add(faHatWizard);

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

it is not working and vue complains that it cannot find the icon. can this be because the render function is missing? or the App.vue? i don't really know what they do. usually i just copy them, but in this project they are missing and i am unsure if i should add them.

i am also unsure how i should create my vue instance. i have also seen that some people use new Vue( some stuff here ).$mount(). is this different from using "el: '#app'", or the same? or like this:

```
createApp(App)
    .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .mount("#app");
```

is there a best practice?

thank you very much for any help!

Comment: What is the exact error? "or like this" - this is the code for Vue 3. The question doesn't say which version is in use.

Comment: There are two active versions of Vue which is Vue 2 and Vue 3. For Vue 2 you use `new Vue`, for Vue 3 you use `createApp`. If you not specify `render` function, Vue will use template or in-DOM HTML template. See https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#render.